# Predicting stock price 'x' days into the future using python & machine learning (LSTM)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIUxPv5PJOY to predict the stock price of Apple one day into the future. The code is:

```
#Import the libraries
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

#Get the stock quote
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2020-12-07')

#Show the data
df
#Get the number of rows and columns in the data set
df.shape

#Visualize the closing price history
#We create a plot with name 'Close Price History'
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Close Price History')
#We give the plot the data (the closing price of our stock)
plt.plot(df['Close'])
#We label the axis
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)', fontsize=18)
#We show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
#Create a new dataframe with only the 'Close' column
data = df.filter(['Close'])

#Convert the dataframe to a numpy array
dataset = data.values
#Get the number of rows to train the model on
training_data_len = math.ceil( len(dataset) * 0.8 )

training_data_len

#Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

scaled_data

#Create the training data set 
#Create the scaled training data set
train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]
#Split the data into x_train and y_train data sets
x_train = []
y_train = []
#We create a loop
for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
  x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0]) #Will conaint 60 values (0-59)
  y_train.append(train_data[i, 0]) #Will contain the 61th value (60)
  if i <= 60:
    print(x_train)
    print(y_train)
    print()


#Convert the x_train and y_train to numpy arrays
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

#Reshape the data
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_train.shape

#Build the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))

#Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

#Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)

#Create the testing data set
#Create a new array containing scaled values from index 1738 to 2247
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 60:]
#Create the data set x_test and y_test
x_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
  x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

#Convert the data to a numpy array
x_test = np.array(x_test)

#Reshape the data
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

#Get the model's predicted price values for the x_test data set
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
predictions

#Evaluate model (get the root mean quared error (RMSE))
rmse = np.sqrt( np.mean( predictions - y_test )**2 )
rmse

#Plot the data
train = data[:training_data_len]
valid = data[training_data_len:]
valid['Predictions'] = predictions
#Visualize the data
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to extend the predicted portion of the graph to show future dates as well ('x' days into the future). I think I could do it by getting the predicted price for the next day and then use that price in the input to get the next day, and then use that day to get the next day, and so on. How can I do it? I thought of appending the next day pred price to the dataset used to train the model, but I wasn't successful at this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. I have done what you were thinking of in this way:

```
X_FUTURE = 100
predictions = np.array([])
last = x_test[-1]
for i in range(X_FUTURE):
  curr_prediction = model.predict(np.array([last]))
  print(curr_prediction)
  last = np.concatenate([last[1:], curr_prediction])
  predictions = np.concatenate([predictions, curr_prediction[0]])
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform([predictions])[0]
print(predictions)
```

I have basically constructed shifting arrays with the new predictions

After that I have constructed the dataframe that contains the new prediction:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
dicts = []
curr_date = data.index[-1]
for i in range(X_FUTURE):
  curr_date = curr_date + timedelta(days=1)
  dicts.append({'Predictions':predictions[i], "Date": curr_date})

new_data = pd.DataFrame(dicts).set_index("Date")
```

And I plotted the result:

```
#Plot the data
train = data
#Visualize the data
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(new_data['Predictions'])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Why it seems so bad (anyway we don't know the future...)? **I did retrain the model on all the  dataset, but the problem here is that the further I go the greater would be the uncertain**. I am not too expert of time series prediction, but I think that the model has not learned any good pattern under the time series. But as example it does what it needs to do

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this.